# Clipping extent is not matching shape

Tags: raster, polygon, qgis-3, clip

Instead, it is only clipping a rectangle.

I have not used in QGIS in a while so maybe I'm missing a step?

Create shapefile (polygon in this case) > raster > extraction > clip raster by extent > clipping extent (polygon)

Output:

[image]

the light grey is the original image, and the slightly darker image is the ''clipped'' image.
Note how it does not match the polygon.

I am using QGIS 3.16.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step you've missed is clipping raster by mask layer instead of clipping by extent.
The result you got is the expected results for clipping by extent.
You can check the documentation here for more details
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html

Comment: Great! this worked. Thank you for the refresher and help.